# Riak - Riak failed to start within 15 seconds,

Tags: riak

Despiste deceptively easy to follow riak install instructions for ubuntu, I get the below error.

```
service riak start
Riak failed to start within 15 seconds,
see the output of 'riak console' for more information.
If you want to wait longer, set the environment variable
WAIT_FOR_ERLANG to the number of seconds to wait.
```

1) I updated the ip address in vm.args and app.config file and restarted riak
2) I ran the below:

```
riak-admin reip riak@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 
Attempting to restart script through sudo -u riak
Usage riak-admin reip <old_nodename> <new_nodename>
```

What is are the riak docs telling me from https://wiki.basho.com/Basic-Cluster-Setup.html?

Comment: What are your ulimit settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> see the output of 'riak console' for more information.

Was there anything in 'riak console' worth sharing?

> Usage riak-admin reip

This takes two arguments. It looks like you've only supplied one.

Feel free to pop into #riak on freenode if you want some realtime assistance.

Comment: oh..you mean this riak-admin reip riak@127.0.0.1 riak@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx versus what I did reip riak@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.riak.user/9102

It is a RIAK packaging problem, you have to delete the ring folder for RIAK node(s) and restart again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, it turned out to be that I had forgotten to install libssl0.9.8.

Try using these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl0.9.8

sudo service riak restart
```

With earlier versions it is not even possible to install Riak without having libssl0.9.8, but in the latest version 1.2.0 I did not see any dependency warning and Riak starts as long as you only bind to 127.0.0.1. At least that is what I observed, the actual root cause might be something else.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using (currently the latest) Riak 1.1.4, try pulling down the previous 1.1.2 version.

I had the same error and tried various combinations of Erlang and Riak versions; going to an earlier version of Riak seemed to do the trick.