# Riak not starting

Tags: riak

I have installed riak and erlang as mentioned in the basho website.
But when i try to start riak with the command:
/etc/init.d/riak start
or
service riak start
I get the following error:
**Starting Riak: Riak failed to start within 15 seconds,
see the output of 'riak console' for more information.
If you want to wait longer, set the environment variable
WAIT_FOR_ERLANG to the number of seconds to wait**
I also checked with the command: riak ping, which gave the error:
**Attempting to restart script through sudo -H -u riak
Node 'riak@sys_ip' not responding to pings**
I am using 64 bit Centos 6.3 machine. Can anybody help me with this?

Initially when i had installed riak and checked the status, it showed that riak had started. Somewhere during the experimentation, it has stopped working. Not able to find, as to what might be the reason?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all ! I found the solution to my problem. I was running the commands as root user. When I tried using the same commands as non-root user with sudo prefix, everything just worked fine ! :)

Comment: why is that the problem though?

Answer (score 1):

Try running following command, it runs diagnostic test over configuration settings and gives more verbose information if there is anything wrong.

```
riak console
```

`riak start` by default doesn't give verbose information about the issue. In my case issue was - missing write permissions on directory - `/var/lib/riak/generated.configs`.

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't mention any version of Erlang, I would like to inform you that using Erlang R15B02 causes  error with riak-admin status.It's better to use Erlang R15B01 with Riak 1.2 and 1.2.1. Riak 1.0 requires Erlang R15B03 and later versions.So, check whether you have installed compatible versions.And if that's not the issue, here is the same issue as yours. [Riak - Riak failed to start within 15 seconds,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640213/riak-riak-failed-to-start-within-15-seconds)

Comment: I am using riak version riak (1.2.1 2012-10-16) RedHat x86_64 and erlang version  R15B01 as you have mentioned. I still have this error persisting.

Comment: @Alaka I am not sure of the issue then,but it may be packaging problem.You need to delete the ring folder for RIAK node(s) and restart again. Check this out  http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.riak.user/9102

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have already checked these links.   I have also deleted the ring directory. Modified app.config and vm.args files with appropriate ip address. Am still not able to get riak up and working.